# static DBContext returning incorrect values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I have a situation where a helper class with a static DBContext member is populating models' boolean fields with different values than a non-static DBContext variable does. The latter is getting the correct variables.

In this case, I have a user with specified username in the database where "isAdmin" is set to true. The static member is returning a User object with isAdmin = false, the other is returning it with true as expected. See below.

Anyone know why this would happen?

Here is the model:

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool isAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

And the problematic helper class looks like this:

```
public static class UserAuthHelper
{
    private static SSBPDContext db = new SSBPDContext();
    public static User getUser(string username, string plaintextPassword)
    {
        var users = db.Users.Where(u => u.username.Equals(username));

        User user = (from u in db.Users
                     where u.username.Equals(username)
                     select u).FirstOrDefault();
        //this user has isAdmin = false
        User otherUser;
        using (var db2 = new SSBPDContext())
        {
            otherUser = (from u in db2.Users
                         where u.username.Equals(username)
                         select u).FirstOrDefault();
            //otherUser has isAdmin = true
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# MVC3 - " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because a DBContext caches the entities you request, so the next time you ask the same DBContext for the same entity it will just get it from memory, and not query the database again for it. As such, every change to that entity outside of that DBContext will be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Your context should not be static. Create one per request. Dependency injection can help you with this (that's a separate question/answer)

The context is not thread safe so it's not even worth trying to figure out the issue here.

Comment: Thread safety shouldn't be an issue here. I'm running this locally with one line in the Users database, and the static context populates the boolean field wrong every time.

It's good to know that it's not threadsafe, and I won't use it like this anymore, but I was hoping for some insight into why this would happen at all.

Comment: without seeing anything else its hard to say here plus there may be missing details, for example - are they both looking to the same database? are you sure? one explanation would be one context doesn't have a connect string (or can't find it-incorrect one) and is creating the database with initialized data. you may yell at me here and say 'no way I don't initialize any data' and Id say fair enough, but I can't tell from the details posted. What db engine are you using? Load up sql profile to check the queries going across or use EFProf trial to profile the context/queries to provide insight.

Comment: They're the same context, and I'm fairly certain it's hitting the right database - all the other fields (left out here for brevity) are getting populated correctly.
I'm using SQLCompact at the moment (building my first MVC app). Thanks for the SQL profiler tip, I'll look into that.

Comment: if you want to send me a sample app, I'll check it out for you I'm first.last at gmail.com

Comment: Huh. according to the [MDSN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=VS.103).aspx) DBContext is threadsafe if it is a `public static` object. Is the documentation wrong?

Comment: Take this issue (more important beyond thread safety...ill have to recheck internals fr above stmt.. Although it is recommended everywhere to have one context per request) user a updates a Customer entity in the context but doesn't yet save the changes as more work is happening. User b queries this same Customer thinking its coming from the database, but instead unexpectedly  gets user a's copy which hasn't even been saved yet. This alone is reason to not even consider it further.